# Is it possible to forecast timeseries using wavelets?

Tags: python, time-series, fft, wavelet-transform, pywt

I have a bunch of minute data that have many seasonalities (day, week, month, year).
I want to make a long forecast of it using wavelet transforms.

By this moment I've made a fourier transform and got an expression for predicting the daily seasonality.
So I've extracted frequencies and amplitudes for sine functions.
[Seasonal trend (orange) and reconstructed seasonal trend(blue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP08f.png) 
The blue curve is the sum of 5 sine functions with known amplitudes and frequencies. And if I fit x-values to this equation I get y-values.

Also I'm trying to make the same thing with wavelet transformation (using pywt).

```
import numpy as np
import pywt
x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=2048)
chirp_signal = np.sin(250 * np.pi * x**2)
data = chirp_signal

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,10))
ax.set_title("Original Signal: ")
ax.plot(data)
plt.show()

waveletname = 'sym5'

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=2, figsize=(40,10))
for ii in range(5):
    (data, coeff_d) = pywt.dwt(data, waveletname)
    axarr[ii, 0].plot(data, 'r')
    axarr[ii, 1].plot(coeff_d, 'g')
    axarr[ii, 0].set_ylabel("Level {}".format(ii + 1), fontsize=20, rotation=90)
    axarr[ii, 0].set_yticklabels([])
    if ii == 0:
        axarr[ii, 0].set_title("Approximation coefficients", fontsize=20)
        axarr[ii, 1].set_title("Detail coefficients", fontsize=20)
    axarr[ii, 1].set_yticklabels([])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The example is from [this guide](http://ataspinar.com/2018/12/21/a-guide-for-using-the-wavelet-transform-in-machine-learning/).

**And the question** is: Is it possible (and if "yes" then how) to make a function with received coefficients, fit x-values to it and get corresponding y-values?

Thanks!